# how to insert keys from token list in command

Tags: luatex, lists, expl3, l3keys, token

When i try to insert in command variable with keys,i get an error:

LaTeX3 Error: The key '__tag/mc/\g__last_mc_tl' is unknown and is being
(LaTeX3)        ignored.

I understand, why this happen. It hapen because according to expl3 documentation,l3keys convert argument as string,so instead of variable,i give variable name. But i haven't any idea,how to fix it. Thanks everybody very much for the help.

```
\RequirePackage[patches]{pdfresources}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{pdfversion=2.0}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true}
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \g__mc_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g__mc_tl{tag=P,actualtext=test of paragraph}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{\g__last_mc_tl}
Test
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\ExplSyntaxOff
\tagstructend
\end{document}=
```

Comment: `\expandafter\tagmcbegin\expandafter{\g__last_mc_tl}`, or in latex3's way `\exp_args:No\tagmcbegin{\g__last_mc_tl}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z Thank you very much for your help. Why we use o param in exp_args  as second  argument instead  of,for example,x or v?

Comment: And why for \expandaftewr we should use it twice,i.e why we need in double expanding?

Comment: 1) To get the value stored in a latex3 `tl` variable, `o` (expand once) and `V` (get the value of variable) are more or less equivalent, though I guess `o` would be faster. `x` or `e` (exhaustive expansion) might fail if, for example `\tl_gset:Nn \g__mc_tl{key=\def\x{}}`. 2) In `\tagmcbegin{\g__last_mc_tl}`, we want to firstly expand the third token `\g__last_mc_tl` once, hence the first two tokens (`\tagmcbegin` and `{`) are prefixed by `\expandater`s.